# EMULSION FRAMEWORK INSTALLATION

Tags: python

I'm a veterinary student pursuing a study in epidemiology. I'm trying to use the Emulsion framework which is a python-based software.

I tried installing it by the letter but when i try to run a test simulation, this is what is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\emulsion.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\emulsion\__main__.py", line 185, in <module>
    from   emulsion.tools.plot          import plot_outputs
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\emulsion\tools\plot.py", line 70, in <module>
    from   bokeh.layouts                import gridplot, column, widgetbox
ImportError: cannot import name 'widgetbox' from 'bokeh.layouts' (c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\bokeh\layouts.py)
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: I suggest you contact the maintainer.  All of the source code links I can find for emulsion are broken. (FWIW - >your< problem is probably caused by a broken dependency.)

Comment: If this is just a problem with installing and using this software, then it not a Programming question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've actually already installed it. I'm just taking a step-by-step approach and trying to verify if it works. Just thought some might know something about it. but anyway, thanks!

Comment: And they don't.  In short, the installation instructions are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'widgetbox' from 'bokeh.layouts'

Looks like widgetbox was removed from bokeh [in version 3.0.0](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9334).

The most recent version of bokeh which has widgetbox is [2.4.3](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#release-2-4-3).

The tool pip can be used to install specific versions of a package:

```
pip install bokeh==2.4.3
```

Comment: And ... if `pip3 install emulsion` is not taking care of that, then emulsion's dependencies (e.g. `requirements.txt`) are broken.  That's a bug. Contact the maintainers.  Especially since they seem to have (erm) hidden their source code repository.

Comment: @StephenC The source code repo can be found here: `git clone https://git.renater.fr/anonscm/git/emulsion-public/emulsion-public.git` Weirdly, it doesn't seem to include setup.py, even though that's distributed in the wheels on PyPI. Academic code, man.

Comment: That's interesting.  According to PyPi, the source code is here: https://git.renater.fr/emulsion-public.git.  And according to https://sourcesup.renater.fr/projects/emulsion-public/ it is here: https//git.renater.fr/anonscm/git/emulsion-public/emulsion-public.git.  And neither of those work.

Comment: And yes ... "academic code".  But frankly, academics should beat on academics who do this kind of shoddy stuff.  Hint: Ivan ...